# outer-like calculation on a list that returns vectors of uneven lenghts?

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors that I'd like to test all-vs-all and extract vector intersections:

```
mylist = structure(
    list(c(1L, 19L, 27L, 46L, 61L, 86L, 1352L, 1408L, 
           654L, 1809L, 768L, 2126L, 240L, 2478L, 1026L, 386L, 2676L, 
           243L, 2887L, 2949L, 2992L, 659L, 3079L, 1009L, 254L, 3326L, 3391L), 
         integer(0), 
         c(18L, 27L, 1100L, 86L, 175L, 1403L,
           626L, 385L, 985L, 153L, 2498L, 2617L, 2771L, 243L, 3126L, 112L, 
           3209L, 3236L, 3360L, 3379L, 3391L, 896L), 
         c(18L, 27L,
           175L, 1487L, 2021L, 2033L, 369L, 893L, 243L, 889L, 3052L, 799L, 
           559L), 
         c(18L, 42L, 61L, 1187L, 1902L, 2101L, 2189L, 2191L, 
           2201L, 985L, 253L, 2555L, 2692L, 2748L, 243L, 956L, 3137L, 94L)
         )
    )
```

I'd like to calculate pairwise vector intersections (with `intersect`) of all combinations and store them in something that I can access by two indices (matrix-like).

```
> intersect(mylist[[1]], mylist[[2]])
integer(0)
> intersect(mylist[[1]], mylist[[3]])
[1]   27   86  243 3391
> intersect(mylist[[1]], mylist[[4]])
[1]  27 243
... etc ...
```

I have tried `outer` but I get the following error:

```
> outer(mylist, mylist, intersect)
Error in outer(mylist, mylist, intersect) : 
  dims [product 25] do not match the length of object [5]
```

I suppose this is because `outer` returns a matrix.

Is there any way other than inefficient double loop approach? My original list has ~10k vectors and it takes forever to do it by looping.

thanks!

Comment: If you really need to calculate the intersection of every `mylist[[i]] ` vs. `mylist[[j!=i]]`  then the loop code is inconsequential. It's the 10k + (10k-1) + (10k-2) +... intersection calculations that are taking so long.  So I ask (as always): what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  There's probably a much better way to analyze your dataset.

Comment: Each element of the vector is an index to a table of properties. Each property is associated with a weighting factor. I'm trying to construct the distance matrix, first by determining all properties common to a pair of entries, then I'll apply a metric based on the number of shared properties and their weights.

Comment: The phrase "to test all-vs-all" is not helpful to me in understanding what is desired (and you didn't say what a correct answer would look like.). Can you use either natural language or a standard database description of what is needed?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a bit of a guess:

```
combidxs <- combn( 1:length(mylist), 2)
combidxs
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
#[2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
 possible <- sapply( 1:10, function(n) 
           intersect( mylist[[ combidxs[1,n] ]], 
                      mylist[[ combidxs[2,n] ]])
                   )

> str(possible)
List of 10
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int [1:4] 27 86 243 3391
 $ : int [1:2] 27 243
 $ : int [1:2] 61 243
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int(0) 
 $ : int [1:4] 18 27 175 243
 $ : int [1:3] 18 985 243
 $ : int [1:2] 18 243
```

`intersect` is not suitable for `outer` since it does not return an object of the same length as its arguments. You can however, use the function Vectorize which returns a new function that can be used with `outer`. Look at:

```
Vintersect <- Vectorize(intersect)
str( outer(mylist, mylist, Vintersect) )
```

You do get the results of `intersect` on each item with itself ... the diagonal of `outer` so to speak ... as well as two of every other intersection..